# Need to rewrite php? url to url with folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm driving my site with php and need to rewrite a specific php url call to a folder... the example is on my local site before uploading hence no http://www.etc

The php is a simple href call `<a href="?id=blog"></a>` that appears in the address bar as `wip_04/?id=blog` or `wip_04/index.php?id=blog` (depending upon whether you go to index.php to begin with) - wip_04 is my offline site root.

I want to rewrite to `wip_04/blog` or even `wip_04/blog/index.php`.

The full example would be from `http://website.co.uk/?id=blog` to `http://website.co.uk/blog/` - there's another index.php inside blog/

I'm not looking for a general rewrite rule but one for this specific instance and I'm stumped.

Any help greatly appreciated.

//Simon

Answer (score 0):

To internally rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=blog
RewriteRule ^/?(index\.php)?$ /blog/ [L]
```

If you want to redirect the browser so that the URL in the address bar changes, add a `R` to the flags s othat they look like `[L,R=301]`

Comment: Thank you very much for the rapid response! I'm trying to incorporate a blog into my site and this will help me enormously - regular expressions I usually do ok with but rewrite rules still evade me, need a bit more practice I guess!!